# How to configure Jboss7 to work with HTTP on port 80

Tags: jboss

I don't have large experience with Jboss but I need to configure Jboss 7 to work on port 80 with HTTPs.

How I can do this?

tks guys

Comment: This might be better asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) but either way we'll need some more information.  Firstly, port 80 is HTTP.  Port 443 it HTTPS.  Second, is there another server in front of JBoss (i.e. Apache, Nginx, etc.)?  Lastly, have you had a chance to read [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the port default in the socket bindings:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
```

Note as well that you can leave the defaults alone and add a new socket binding.

Comment: So you can start Jboss7 with -Djboss.https.port=443 or/and -Djboss.http.port=80